# Parameters and restrictions of a Single-satellite and Single Ground Station system

Tags: low-earth-orbit

I am designing a ground station system  to retrieve data from a single satellite sending at a given bandwidth in LEO, and I am confused of which parameters I have to take into account when designing a system like this and also the restrictions of the system.

My thoughts so fare:

Restrictions: 
LEO satellites have a high orbital speed, and because of this the ground station can only communicate with the satellite for a brief period when the satellite is about the stations horizon plane.

Any thoughts of more restrictions of the system and which parameters I have to take into account?

Comment: Welcome to Space Exploration SE!  The scope of your question might include a broad variety of topics, including learning when/where your target satellite is visible, designing an antenna, decoding the communications, legal issues, and so on.  Please either post separate questions for each aspect you need answered, or modify this question to a narrower scope.  Thanks!

Comment: In short: simply give more information, to make an adequate answer shorter than a book. :-)

Comment: Communication periods are short in duration but close, say 400 to 1200 km. Putting the satellite in GEO moves it 35x farther away which means you'd need some combination of a larger antenna (more gain) and more power for the same received signal strength on Earth, However you'd be line-of-sight constantly so you could transmit data at lower received power by using a lower speed. Advantage is reduced latency; if something suddenly happened the GEO satellite could announce it instantly but the LEO satellite would have to wait for the next pass over the ground station.